# problem with Multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to do a table in latex.
My problem is I cannot to a multirow for "Apprentissage"  cell between the 3 cell : "phrase", "mot" and "vocabulaire"

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Corpus} & Français & Anglais & Allemand   \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Apprentissage} & phrases & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{600.000} \\ \hline
&   Mot & ? & ? & ? \\ \hline
& Vocabulaire & ? & ? & ? \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caractéristique du corpus \textsc{Europarl}}
\label{fig:typeDistribution}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\cline{n-m}` instead of `\hline`.

```
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Corpus} & Français & Anglais & Allemand   \\ \hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{Apprentissage} & phrases & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{600.000} \\ \cline{2-5}
 &   Mot & ? & ? & ? \\ \cline{2-5}
 & Vocabulaire & ? & ? & ? \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Caractéristique du corpus \textsc{Europarl}}
 \label{fig:typeDistribution}
 \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Multirow` doesn't override `\hline`. Instead of them, you should use `\cline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Corpus}    & Français  & Anglais   & Allemand   \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Apprentissage}  & phrases   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{600.000}  \\ \cline{2-5}
                                & Mot & ? & ? & ?                           \\ \cline{2-5}
                                & Vocabulaire & ? & ? & ?                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caractéristique du corpus \textsc{Europarl}}
\label{fig:typeDistribution}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your "français" is missing the `ç`. :P

Comment: I see. Since I need to construct MWE myself, I didn't pay attention on French langue, i.e. adequate font coding ... I will try to correct this.

Comment: I think adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` should be enough! :)

Comment: Yes, it is. Anyway I also added      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. To be MWE more complete :-). Can you me tell, how you highlight latex code in your comment. I like to do on the same way, but for now I unsuccessfully search how to do this ...

Comment: You need to use back ticks, like ``. Add the word(s) in the middle.

Comment: Like this ``test``? Hey, this work! Thank you very much!

Comment: Zarko, I fixed your image, hope you don't mind! :P

Comment: Alenanno, huh, I correct the code but forget to upload new picture! Thank you that you do this instead me.