# problem table, multirow and UTF8 error

Tags: tables, miktex, texmaker, unicode, multirow

I am beginner with Latex (windows 10, Texmaker and Miktex) and I would like to reproduce this kind of table :

[image]

I thought that this question could help me : [problem with Multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245434/problem-with-multirow). But when I tried to compile @Zarko 's answer, I have this error : ! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. I didn't manage to fix it...
Please, any clue would be great (whether on UTF or table problem) !

Kindly yours

EDIT :

Here is the code I copied-pasted :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Corpus}    & Français  & Anglais   & Allemand   \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Apprentissage}  & phrases   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{600.000}  \\ \cline{2-5}
                                & Mot & ? & ? & ?                           \\ \cline{2-5}
                                & Vocabulaire & ? & ? & ?                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caractéristique du corpus \textsc{Europarl}}
\label{fig:typeDistribution}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Whether I remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` it doesn't compile anything.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post what you tried?

Comment: I test my answer in given link again. It still works fine. Meanwhile for recent version of the article package `utf8` is default  input encoding, so in my answer you can remove code line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. However, please check, how old is your LaTeX installation. It may now be a time to update it now :-)

Comment: What cause your problem is not possible to figured out without seeing a MWE (a small complete document with your table), which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko I have recieved this error sometime because of when I copy and paste from a web site you et some strange characters with you. Often a ligature.

Comment: @Sveinung, yeah, sometimes I faced with invisible characters in codes provided here on site, which make unexpected troubles. That is reason more, that OP provide MWE. However, in this case this now is not relevant anymore since some good souls already  write own MWE for OP ... :-)

Comment: Hi @Zarko , I copied-pasted your example directly. Even with removing \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} , I have the same error... I have installed the latest release of Texmaker and Miktex. However, how to get OP and MWE ?

Comment: Please show us your test file, which reproduce your error. Let be minimal and complete (compilable as it is) but should reproduce your error.

Comment: I test your MWE, it works fine.

Comment: @Zarko , OK, probably a configuration problem. Looks like I will have to dig into it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table can be done like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
& & Parameters A & Parameters B & Parameters C\\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Cell 1} & Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
 & Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
 & Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
 \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Cell 1} & Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
 & Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
 & Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you employ the `booktabs` package for its macros that can generate well-spaced horizontal rules -- specifically, the `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` macros -- and the `multirow` package for its `\multirow` command. Observe that the first argument of `\multirow` need *not* be integer-valued.

While you're at it, you may also want to provide a bit more visual structure to the header material. Doing so lets you snug up rows 3 to 5 to rows 1 and 2.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\sffamily % optional
\begin{tabular}{@{}llccc@{}}
%\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Parameters}\\
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
& & A & B & C\\
\midrule
\multirow{4.4}{*}{Cell 1} 
    & Value 1  & 1A1 & 1B1 & 1C1\\
    & Value 2  & 1A2 & 1B2 & 1C2\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & Value 3  & 1A3 & 1B3 & 1C3\\
    & Value 4  & 1A4 & 1B4 & 1C4\\
\midrule
\multirow{4.4}{*}{Cell 2} 
    & Value 1  & 2A1 & 2B1 & 2C1\\
    & Value 2  & 2A2 & 2B2 & 2C2\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & Value 3  & 2A3 & 2B3 & 2C3\\
    & Value 4  & 2A4 & 2B4 & 2C4\\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```